# Schema design in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I need help to model a database in MongoDB.

The model below shows performance problems.

```
- Collection users
    - email
    - hash
    - store
        - name
        - adress
        - logo
        - products
            - name
            - value
            - description
            - image
            - featured
            - categories
                - id_category

- Collection category
    - id
    - name
```

In the system the user can have a shop and the shop have many products and the products have many categories.

The problem is when I want to put a product featured on the home page , the system will search for all users , which is not good.

I thought about putting the products in another collection , but that would think of " relational " mode, which MongoDB is not .

Answer (score 0):

You can do relational in MongoDB it just isn't build with that in mind so you will have to pay attentions to the things that relational databases would usually pay attention to for you and you will also have to work arround things that are missing like joins. But that doesn't mean you can't do relational and if you look at your schema you are already doing the categories relational.

Also since you are storing images with the product and a shop can have a lot of products you will probably run into the 16MB document size limit sooner or later.

A product collection is probably the right way for you given the information from the question.

Answer (score 0):

Since your user have many products, I think its better to put "product" in another collection.

Note that MongoDB has a limit of 16 MB for a single document.

You can do something like the following:

```
- Collection users
    - email
    - hash
    - store
        - name
        - adress
        - logo
        - products :[product1ID, product2ID,...]
- Collection Product
        - ProductID  
        - name
        - value
        - description
        - image
        - featured
        - categories
                - id_category
- Collection category
    - id
    - name
```

Embedded document model is not a good choice for many-to-many relation. Using normalized data model can clarify the schema, save disk space. Although you would have to run multiple queries for a "JOIN".
For more detail, you can read the data model section of the official manual:http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/